# how to run some lines at the initialization of my django api in production?

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I build an API in django, it worked perfectly until I tried to deploy it with gunicorn and nginx.

I initiate some constants at the beginning of my views.py. So my code looks like this before defining all my views.

```
from ... import...

x = do_big_stuff()
y = do_big_stuff2()
z = do_big_stuff3()
```

I do this to init x, y and z at the launching of the api (so when I enter `python manage.py runserver`)

I use x, y and z in all my views after this. This init takes approximately 15 seconds then a request will take less than 1 second. It's not a problem

But since I deployed this API with gunicorn and nginx I meet an issue : it looks like this lines are ran at EACH request. So it takes so much time and user always get "502 bad gateway" and I can see in my logs

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:23605)
```

So i commented these lines and just add a `print("hello world")` to check and realised that hello world was printed at each request ... That was not the case during development.

I assume my method is not good, but could anyone advice me please ?

Comment: Could you explain why you need x, y, z and what are they ?

Comment: the variable initialization code is at module root, not in the view function, right?

Comment: Hunch: I don't know gunicorn but I think multiple Python processes are spawned. How many may be created? Maybe the overhead you experience is because at each request a new process is spawned and the costly module is initialized. 
Have you tried making a certain number of requests so that maybe you use already spawned Python processes?

Comment: @MichałDarowny I'm proposing 3 chatbots to my users, so there are 2 functions , a chatbot_init() which is the "big stuff" and takes long time. And a chatbot() function which use these 3 constants

Comment: @OlivierH only 3 are created. Yes I think each request call a new process, and that's not what I want unfortanetly ... I would run one process then users could call my routes with constants inside

Comment: Are you running your wsgi container with `--daemon` option? From what I read from gurnicorn's documentation, it may be needed to keep the process in the background once spawned.
-
Also, the nginx proxy may need to have a longer timeout, just in case (again, i'll be of no help as I don't know nginx, but I know that the timeout is customizable with httpd's mod_proxy, so I guess it's the same with nginx)

Comment: Notice: If you find a way around this, please post your solution as an answer under your question.

Comment: @LucieDevGirl so If I understand correctly some views use methods of chatbot object ? and chatbot is configured using x y z?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving these lines in my wsgi.py ! Gunicorn will run this one only once then I import x, y , z from myproject.wsgi and that's all :)

And for the timeout, just added --timeout 120 in my gunicorn command

thank's for your help